# want to disable past date and future date too

Tags: javascript, html

working on datepicker its not working 
i fount solution on stack but its not working 
i tried many solution but did not get dezire output

```js
$(function(){
    $('.om').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        startDate:'1d',
        endDate: '+2m',
        
        autoclose: true
    }); 
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="om">
```

Comment: solved i have added few links then its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try minDate: and maxDate: instead of startDate and endDate

Answer (score 0):

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
       minDate: 0
     });
  });

Answer (score 0):

User minDate & maxDate

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

```
$(function(){
    $('.om').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        minDate:0,
        maxDate: '+2m',
        autoclose: true
    }); 
});
```